# Angular Unit-Test MockService still throws Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm stuck on this again and although this thread ([MockService still causes error: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134575/mockservice-still-causes-error-cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined)) is exactly about the same thing it still doesn't resolve my problem.

I do have a component which calls a simple function on ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getModules();
}

getModules() {
  this.configService.getModulesToDisplay().subscribe(modules => {
    this.modulesToDisplay = modules;
    }
  );
}
```

I want to test two things:

Is `getModules` called on `ngOnInit`

and

Is `this.modulesToDisplayed` reassigned when it gets some result

So I mocked my service but the first test still fails with the TypeError 'Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'.

I moved my mocked Service to all different areas since I do guess the mock isn't available when the test starts to build the component. But I still couldn't make it out. My Test looks like:

```
describe('NavigationComponent', () => {
  let component: NavigationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavigationComponent>;
  let configServiceMock: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    configServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('ConfigService', ['getModulesToDisplay']);
    configServiceMock.getModulesToDisplay.and.returnValue( of(['module1', 'module2']) );

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        NavigationComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ConfigService, useValue: configServiceMock },
      ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    }).compileComponents();

  beforeEach(() => {
    // configServiceMock.getModulesToDisplay.and.returnValue( of(['module1', 'module2']) );
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavigationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
  }));
```

I removed fixture.detectChanges() to have full control over when ngOnInit should be called and so my tests look like:

```
    it('should call getModulesToDisplay one time on ngOninit()', () => {
      const spyGetModules = spyOn(component, 'getModules');
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(spyGetModules).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

The first test fails with the Cannot read subscribe error. But the second one passes with the correct mockvalue being used.

```
  it('should assign result to modulesToDisplay', () => {
    component.getModules();
    expect(component.modulesToDisplay.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
```

Any hints on what am I still missing are highly appreciated!

Comment: *"Is getModules called on ngOnInit"* is **not** something you want to test. That's an internal detail of the component, `getModules` could probably be private, you want to test that it interacts correctly with the test double of the collaborator. Don't call the method directly, only invoke it via `ngOnInit`, so you have the freedom to refactor within the class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do get your point and will delete the ngOnInit Test. Although I'm still wondering why it works in the example of the link I've posted in my question but not in my setup. I's still love to know if the returned value of a mocked service is already available when the test compiles the Component.

Comment: @BreadcrumbPie : Did u try my reusable approach ? I see a downvote. Do let me know if you find this irrelevant and I'll delete this

Comment: Sorry for my delayed answer. I fiddled around a while with all different kind of tests (I've seen your blog before, too ;) ) . I think my biggest problem is to find out what test ist really needed. So I decided not to go with the ngOninit Tests at all

Answer (score -2):

Rather than writing jasmine `spy` in each `spec` file, create a reusable `Mock` file

```
export class MockConfigService{
   getModulesToDisplay(){
     return of({
         // whatever module object structure is
     })
   }
}
```

and in `it` block:

```
    it('should call getModulesToDisplay one time on ngOninit()', () => {
      spyOn(component, 'getModules').and.callThrough();
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.getModules).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```